# Coinbase address callbacks not working?

Tags: bitcoin

I'm using the Coinbase API. My app generates new receive addresses with callbacks. However, when BTC arrives at any of those addresses, the callbacks don't seem to be firing.

I've verified that the callbacks are indeed being created for the new addresses, and that my app would respond correctly to the callbacks. For instance, this triggers the desired functionality on my server:

```
curl --data "address=someaddress&amount=1.2" https://mydomain.com/callback?secret_token=mysecret
```

Alas, there are no calls being made to my server whatsoever (any call would show up in the logs, but none do).

Anyone using Coinbase address callbacks successfully? Any hints for debugging this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a json request with php to set the callback url? If you login and look at the addresses section, do you see the correct url in the callback section? Make sure there is no typo. I was able to do this a few months ago but have left the project that did this.

Answer (score -1):

create a php file    callback.php

put this code in your callback.php

```
<?php
    $jsonData = file_get_contents('php://input');

    $postDatacoinbase = json_decode($jsonData, true);

    print_r ($postDatacoinbase);

?>
```

login into Coinbase and click on " Merchant settings " and
input your http://mydomain.com/callback.php url into callback url

and click test now to see the results .